# PHP is not creating MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, lamp

So I'm not sure as to why PHP is not creating a database. Let me show what my code looks like first, and then I will quote what warning/error it's giving me:

```
<?php
    // Connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1monica1");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // Creating a database
    // The database is called alarm_db
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE alarm_db";
    if (mysql_query($sql, $con))
    {
        echo "Database alarm_db created sucessfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
?>
```

The error and warning I keep getting is this:

> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in B:\DropBox\Dropbox\EbadlyAgha\Ebad\reminders.php on line 51
>   Error creating database:

Line 51 is where the `if (mysql_query($sql, $con))` is. Also, it won't give me the `mysqli_error($con)`. It is just blank.

My MySQL connection is fine, because I never see the "Failed to connect to MySQL" statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be in `mysqli_*` while you executing DB creating query.

```
if (mysqli_query($sql,$con)) {
    echo "Database alarm_db created sucessfully";
}
```

Try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is being generated by the mysqli library:

```
$con = mysqli_connect
```

but you are trying to query it using the mysql library:

```
mysql_query($sql,$con)
```

You need to be consistent about which library you use. Stick to mysqli throughout (since mysql is deprecated).

Note that mysqli_query expects the connection before the SQL:

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create a database using PHP:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $query = mysql_query('create database alarm_db') or die(mysql_error());
    if($query)
    {
        echo 'Database is created';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Database is not created';
    }
?>
```